# Augmented Reality - What do i need?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, android-augmented-reality

i have to build an app like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vetDCkbQGM4

It should simply detect the cockpit of a car and should show informations. For example "this is air conditioning", "this is switch button for the radio". The targets will be pre defined. Basically the app should detect everything and should show information.

Can I realize this with Vuforia? Which framework is suitable for this task?
I hope you guys can help me.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Since your targets are pre-defined, the simplest solution would be to use aruco markers to get 3D world positions/rotations through your user's camera feed.

See the [AR Marker Detector](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/80086) in the Unity Asset Store for an example. Vuforia uses 'VuMarks' that are more intricate versions of this.

If you can't add computer-readable labels to the real world for your project, then you are talking about real-time object recognition. That is a much harder problem and not yet easily solvable in Unity as far as I know. It would require something like Google's [Cloud Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/). There is a [Unity Cloud Vision project](https://github.com/comoc/UnityCloudVision) on GitHub, but I have no idea how well it works or what it's capabilities are.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible, you were first require to google. There are different SDK/Framework and Unity Asset store packages available.

You can use Free [**Vuforia AR Starter Kit**](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/74050) from asset store to up and run your logic. Or You can also use [**Free AR Toolkit**](https://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=6_Unity:unity_about). There are different kind of tut available which can show you how to implement these pacakges.